# How to upload and use any font on website?

Tags: css, fonts, upload, google-font-api

I would like to know If we can upload any font on our website ??
Where can I download a font or google font and upload it on my css file directly like that :

```
@font-face { font-family: 'Myriad Pro Regular'; 
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 300; 
src: local('Myriad Pro Regular'), url('MYRIADPRO-REGULAR.woff') format('woff'); }
```

instead of use this sort of code :

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans Pro:200italic,200,300italic,300,400italic,400,600italic,600,700italic,700,900italic,900);
```

thank you

Comment: You “can” upload any font that you can get grip on. However, uploading a font for use on the web without the permission of the copyright holder is criminal and stupid at that, since crimes like this are easy to spot. It is unclear what you are asking when referring to “a font or google font” and present the use of Myriad Pro (a commercial font) as an alternative to using Source Sans Pro (a free font) as hosted by Google.

Comment: you're right and am totaly agree, but i need free font (Open sans & Raleway) @JukkaK.Korpela

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [don’t use @import](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/).

Prefere LINK tag :

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='a.css'>
```

Download [Source Sans Pro webfont](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/source-sans-pro) and make CSS file with these rules :

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: SourceSansPro;
    src: url('source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Regular.otf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: SourceSansPro;
    src: url('source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Bold.otf');
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: SourceSansPro;
    src: url('source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Italic.otf');
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: SourceSansPro;
    src: url('source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-BoldItalic.otf');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: SourceSansPro;
    src: url('source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-Light.otf');
    font-weight: 300;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: SourceSansPro;
    src: url('source-sans-pro/SourceSansPro-LightItalic.otf');
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

- [Using a Custom Web Font](http://independentpublisher.me/2013/using-a-custom-web-font/)

Comment: how to donwload an otf file for this font ? and how to download all forms of the font ( regular, italic, light, ... ) in one time ? I have to download the file for all form ?

Comment: perfect your comment helps  me a lot ;D

Comment: try to convert format with : http://everythingfonts.com/otf-to-ttf http://otf2ttf.com/ see on google.

Answer (score 0):

I found this youtube video online. It gives the instructions step by step.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPwG67lEFdc
```

I listed the steps here go to http://www.google.com/fonts/
find a font that you like, click the quick use link. Scroll down again and copy the link that looks like the following.
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Next integrate the fonts into your CSS. The Google Fonts API will generate the necessary browser-specific CSS to use the fonts. All you need to do is add the font name to your CSS styles. For example:

font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

Answer (score -1):

True, like @Jukka said, some fonts aren't free, so you'll have to search. Luck is that:

Raleway - http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/raleway

and Open Sans - http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans

are free, so you just have to download the TTF (big blue button), inside the zip there's the whole set of weights and styles of the font.

Then you have two options:

- Upload the .ttf directly to your ftp and call it into your css, as you stated; or
- Use the Webfont Generator (http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) to create another types (.woof, .eot, .svg), because of browsers.

FYI, Chrome in the last few versions (< 39) had a problem with some fonts, and just the .svg extension corrected the bug.

Comment: thank you hope I can do it with Raleway and Open Sans ;D

Comment: There is no guarantee that fonts on those sites are actually free.

Comment: @DimasPante uploading font in ttf format works too ? there is a difference with otf format when you want to upload it ?

Comment: Only *TTF* will work, but not in all IE versions, as usual (*EOT* is the best option for IE < 8). About *OTF*, they claim it would be a "better" font, accepting more features, but that's was in 2012. See: http://www.whatthehelvetica.com/2012/03/04/what-is-the-difference-between-otf-and-ttf-fonts/